# Call to a templated member function that takes as arguments an object and one of its member function in C++

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member

I am having problems using this declaration.

```
object1.function1<Object2, void (Object2::*)()>(object2, &Object2::function2)
```

This is what the compiler tells me.

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl Object1::function1<class Object2,void (__cdecl Object2::*)(void)>(class Object2 &,void (__cdecl Object2::*)(void))" (??$function1@VObject2@@P81@EAA_NXZ@Object1@@QEAA_NAEAVObject2@@P81@EAA_NXZ@Z)
```

Here the struct of the code:

```
class Object1{
public:
    template <typename O, typename F>
    void function1(O& object, F function){
        object.function();
    }
};

class Object2{
public:
    void function2(){
        std::cout << "Doing something..." << std::endl;
    };
};

class Object3 {
private:

    Object1 object1;
    Object2 object2;

    void function3() {
        object1.function1<Object2, void (Object2::*)()>(object2, &Object2::function2);
    };
};
```

I can not see the error. Someone could help me?

Comment: `std::invoke(function, &object);` in `function1` template.

Comment: @rafix07, `&` can be omitted.

Comment: Take the above code, make a project with *only it* in it (ok you can add a main) in one cpp file, compile, and provide *all compiler output* verbatim.  Include what compiler and the command line if you can.  Because my "in head" compiler gets a different error message from the code you posted, so I think your code is not a [mcve] of your actual problem.  I think you simplified and manually edited the error message, and in doing so made your example not reproduce your problem.  But I could be wrong, my "in head" compiler lacks iso certification.

Comment: If you fix the function names, it compiles fine ([https://www.ideone.com/u05Qd5](https://www.ideone.com/u05Qd5)). Take Yakk's advice.

Comment: Note that you don't have to specify template parameter, as they are deducible, just do `object1.function1(object2, &Object2::function2);`

Comment: @zdf: I suspect OP want to use the member function pointer, not expect a method called `function` in `O`.

Comment: It is a simplification of the original code because it is to complex to understand. When I simplify it, it works, but in the original base code it does not.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
class Object1{
public:
    template <typename O, typename F>
    void function1(O& object, F function){
        object.function();
    }
};
```

`object.function();` doesn't use `F function`.

Syntax for member function pointer would be:

```
(object.*function)();
```

[`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) is superior, as it allows more than just member function

`std::invoke(function, object);`

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/171ddbc8510d8f96)

Comment: What @Jarod42 is right, but the problem still exist.

Comment: @vicalomen: Demo added. link error means missing definition, that you can happen if you forget to build all files together, implment template in cpp files, ...

Comment: Finally I found the error. It appears when you declare the function template in a .cpp class file. I do not why. Do you @Jarod42 know the reason?

Comment: @vicalomen: see [why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)